# For all unit vectors $\mathbf u$ and a positive definite $\mathbf C$, what surface do vectors $\mathbf u \mathbf u^\top \mathbf C \mathbf u$ form?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, conic-sections, surfaces, plane-curves

Let $\mathbf C$ be a positive-definite $k\times k$ matrix. For all vectors $\mathbf u\in \mathbb R^k$ of length $\|\mathbf u\|=1$, consider vectors $\mathbf {uu}^\top\mathbf{Cu}$; they form a surface in $\mathbb R^k$. What is this surface? In particular, what is it in case of $k=2$?

Here is an example for $\mathbf C = \left(\begin{array}{cc}4&2\\2&2\end{array}\right)$:

[image: Weird shape]

I do realize that the "main axes" (the longest and the shortest cuts) of this curve are given by the eigenvectors of $\mathbf C$ scaled by the respective eigenvalues. But the whole shape looks weird.

Comment: It's easier if you choose a coordinate system along the eigenvectors of $\mathbf C$. Then the polar equation of the curve is just $r=\lambda_1\cos^2\theta+\lambda_2\sin^2\theta$ where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the eigenvalues of $\mathbf C$.

Comment: Indeed! Does this curve have a name?

Comment: I don't know, but it creates some pretty odd-looking surfaces in 3D: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5M2Ua.png

Comment: Hmm. Turns out the equation (and also the shape) is very similar to [hippopede](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippopede), a.k.a. lemniscate of Booth, but not quite the same.

Comment: I posted this question separately: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1523908.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write your vectors in the basis of eigenvectors $f_1,\ldots,f_k$ of $C$, then if $u=\sum t_jf_j$ we have
$$
u^TCu=\sum t_j^2\lambda_j,
$$
where $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues of $C$ (counting multiplicities). So, in each direction, you are stretching the unit circle by $\sum t_j^2\lambda_j$ a convex combination of the eigenvalues. In particular, when $u$ is the $j^{\rm th}$ eigenvector, the value is precisely $\lambda_j$.

More explicitly, 
$$
\{uu^TCu:\ \|u\|=1\}=\left\{\left(\sum_{j=1}^kt_j^2\lambda_j\right)\,u:\ u=\sum t_jf_j,\ \sum t_j^2=1\right\}.
$$
When $k=2$, 
$$
\{uu^TCu:\ \|u\|=1\}=\{(\lambda_1\cos^2\theta+\lambda_2\sin^2\theta)\,u:\ \theta\in[0,2\pi],\ u=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\}
$$

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense, but I don't think I understand your first equation: why is $u^\top C u = u^\top \lambda$? Shouldn't it be $\sum u_i^2 \lambda_i$ and not $\sum u_i \lambda_i$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have edited a little.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if the planar curve with polar equation $r=\lambda_1\cos^2\theta+\lambda_2\sin^2\theta$ has a name? Some sort of lemniscate maybe?

Comment: I don't know, sorry.

Comment: Turns out the equation (and also the shape) is very similar to [hippopede](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippopede), a.k.a. lemniscate of Booth, but not quite the same. I am not usually using math.SE and don't have much experience with it; do you think it's worthwhile to post this as a separate question? I will now accept your answer in any case.

Comment: I cannot predict when a question will get answers, even after years here. But it doesn't hurt to try. I assume you noticed that when both $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are above 1 or below 1, the graph is an ellipse.

Comment: Wait, is it really? Simply multiplying $\mathbf C$ from my question by a scalar factor can make its both eigenvalues above or below 1, but this won't change the shape of the curve apart from scaling it.

Comment: You are right. It seems to depend on some relation between $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_1$ (whether it is an ellipse or not) but I cannot immediately figure out the relation.

Comment: Very empirically (and I might be very wrong) it looks like that  ellipse/no ellipse change has to do with whether $$\max\left\{\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2},\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\right\}\geq\frac\pi2.$$

Comment: I posted my question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1523908.

Comment: Good. It already has several upvotes. Let's see if someone answers.