# Does a plane curve with polar equation $r=\lambda_1\cos^2\theta+\lambda_2\sin^2\theta$ have a name?

Tags: terminology, polar-coordinates, plane-curves

Does a plane curve with polar equation $$r=\lambda_1\cos^2\theta+\lambda_2\sin^2\theta$$ where both $\lambda_i>0$ have a name?

It's very similar to [hippopede](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippopede), also known as lemniscate of Booth, but not quite the same: hippopede equation can be written in the same way but with $r^2$ instead of $r$.

Here is how it looks like for $\lambda_2=1$ and $\lambda_1 \in \{\frac{1}{2}, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$:
[image]

**Update:** I realized that in my application it is more natural to put $r^2$ instead of $r$ in the equation above; hence what I appear to be dealing with is a hippopede after all. The family of curves displayed above is likely not to have any name (hard as I tried, I failed to find any).

Comment: I don't know but it is a nice family of curves !

Comment: I don't have a name either. What I can say is that it is a [conchoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conchoid_(mathematics)) of a [four-leaf rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrifolium).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was your application where this appeared?

Comment: Up to rotation, you curve is [Ceva's trisectrix](https://www.2dcurves.com/sextic/sextict.html)

Comment: @gota: Included in the  answer is my  guess.

Answer (score 1):

Do not know its name, may be called ***Euler normal curvature relation***,  a part of the Mohr's circle in differential geometry context:

[image]

Mentioning this due to its possible interest to STEM students. If curvature of normal plane while rotating  through angle $\psi$  at a point on a surface in $\mathbb R^3$ is plotted in the tangent plane of rotating plane  in bundle then it is a representation of Euler's relation

$$ \kappa_n= \kappa_1 \cos^2\psi +\kappa_2  \sin^2 \psi$$

where $(\kappa_1, \kappa_2 )$ are principal curvatures.

Read with Enneper geodesic torsion of all rotated lines of the bundle

$$ \tau_g= (\kappa_1-\kappa_2 ) \cos \psi \sin \psi$$

Please note $\lambda_1 $ can be also negative, for *asymptotic line locus* on negative Gauss curvature doubly curved surfaces.

The relation forms a part of parametrization of the Mohr's circle curvature tensor.

Accordingly the curvature can be replaced by stress, strain, moment of inertia among other tensors. They are often plotted on $(x,y)$ axes respectively.

[Mohr's Circle of tensors Figs 6,8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohr%27s_circle)